# Writing lists inside of dictionaries to Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, scrapy, psycopg2

I've been trying to find a simple solution for this for some time now. Basically I have a list inside my dictionary and I want to write N number of columns to my table in Postgres. For example, sometimes a product can have only one column like in the example below or it can have multiple columns.

Columns are stored in list under `'main_product_table'`.

Basically, my data looks like following:

```
{'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 16, 23, 1, 1),
 'main_category_name': 'Elektronika',
 'main_product_delivery_date': '26.08.2020',
 'main_product_image': 'https://ekupi.blob.core.windows.net/ekupihr/300Wx300H/EK000308027_1.image',
 'main_product_link': 'https://www.ekupi.hr/hr/Elektronika/Televizori-i-oprema/Antenistika/Sobne-antene/ONE-FOR-ALL-ANTENA-SOBNA-SV9435/p/EK000308027',
 'main_product_name': 'ONE FOR ALL ANTENA SOBNA SV9435',
 'main_product_payment_way': 'Platite gotovinom pri preuzimanju, Internet '
                             'bankarstvom, karticama jednokratno i na rate',
 'main_product_price': 309.0,
 'main_product_return': 'Povrat robe moguć unutar 14 dana',
 'main_product_table': [{'Brand': 'ONE FOR ALL'}],
 'sub_category_name': 'Televizori i oprema',
 'sub_sub_category_name': 'Antenistika'}
```

Now, when I was reading about this, I did not really get anywhere, I think. One solution which I am not sure how to implement is the following.

**1.** I would somehow store `main_product_table` in my models.py file and call it for usage later.

**2.** Simply insert with `cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO products(column_1,column_2,...,column_n) VALUES (%(value_1)s, %(value_2)s),...%(value_n)s""", main_product_table)`

I am not sure how to access the list `main_product_table` and I am not even sure if this code would actually work.

Comment: There are multiple questions here. One on creating a list in a dict. The second on using ```executemany```. It is really better to only have one question at a time. So lets start with the list question. What code have you tried? How are you getting the table and column information?

Comment: I am getting table information (columns in table) with the following code:

`temp_product_data["tableColumn1"] = table_rows.xpath("normalize-space(.//td[1]/text())").extract()` 

and the same goes for Column2. Next, I just zip those two columns into one with `dict(zip())` called `main_product_table`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possible ways:

1. If you want to have everything in a **single table**: you need to have JSON-like `main_product_table` field where you need to save your values (`json.dumps(item['main_product_table']`)
2. You can use a **separate** table for this information: you need to save a main record first, get a table `product_id` and next perform a several `INSERT INTO product_details (product_id, property_name, property_value) VALUES (...)` (one per product property)

Comment: That was my initial idea. Basically store every product attribute (under list 'main_product_table') in a different table and make one-to-one relationship in Postgres like you suggested. I am not really sure how would I access `main_product_table` so I could expand it into columns and write values to columns. I would greatly appreciate a hint on this.